# Finding every points in a sphere in a 3d coordinates

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to solve this algorithm.
Given a radius and an a point.
Find every points in the 3d coordinate system that are in the sphere of that radius that centered at the given point, and store them in a list.

Comment: A sphere has an infinite amount of points.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry for confusion but I meant all the point with integer coordinates.

Comment: hint: look at when the sin/cos are fractions.

Comment: Inside the sphere or at the surface of the sphere?

Comment: @JoseMaria It is inside the sphere, thank you for noticing.

Comment: You could just take the cube that is a box around the sphere, subsequently iterate all the 3D coordinates in the cube. If a coordinate has Euclidian distance to the centerpoint smaller than the radius, it is in the sphere. This might not be the fastest algorithm, but its easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this with numpy, below.

Note the code here will give you coordinates relative to a sphere centered at a point you choose, with a radius you choose.  You need to make sure that your input dimensions 'dim' below are set so that the sphere would be fully contained within that volume first.  It also will only work for positive indicies.  If your point has any coordinates that are negative, use the positive of that, and then in the output flip the signs of that axis coordinates yourself.

```
import numpy as np

dim = 15

# get 3 arrays representing indicies along each axis
xx, yy, zz = np.ogrid[:dim, :dim, :dim]

# set you center point and radius you want
center = [7, 7, 7]
radius = 3

# create 3d array with values that are the distance from the
# center squared
d2 = (xx-center[0])**2 + (yy-center[1])**2 + (zz-center[2])**2

# create a logical true/false array based on whether the values in d2
# above are less than radius squared
#
# so this is what you want - all the values within "radius" of the center
# are now set to True
mask = d2 <= radius**2

# calculate distance squared and compare to radius squared to avoid having to use
# slow sqrt()

# now you want to get the indicies from the mask array where the value of the
# array is True.  numpy.nonzero does that, and gives you 3 numpy 1d arrays of
# indicies along each axis
s, t, u = np.nonzero(mask)

# finally, to get what you want, which is all those indicies in a list, zip them together:
coords = list(zip(s, t, u))

print(coords)
>>>
[(2, 5, 6),
 (3, 4, 5),
 (3, 4, 6),
 (3, 4, 7),
 (3, 5, 5),
 (3, 5, 6),
 (3, 5, 7),
 (3, 6, 5),
 (3, 6, 6),
 (3, 6, 7),
 (4, 3, 6),
 (4, 4, 5),
 (4, 4, 6),
 (4, 4, 7),
 (4, 5, 4),
 (4, 5, 5),
 (4, 5, 6),
 (4, 5, 7),
 (4, 5, 8),
 (4, 6, 5),
 (4, 6, 6),
 (4, 6, 7),
 (4, 7, 6),
 (5, 4, 5),
 (5, 4, 6),
 (5, 4, 7),
 (5, 5, 5),
 (5, 5, 6),
 (5, 5, 7),
 (5, 6, 5),
 (5, 6, 6),
 (5, 6, 7),
 (6, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: the other way to do it (perhaps simpler and faster - definitely less memory lol!) is to just do 3 nested for loops over the x,y,z dimensions that would fully enclose the sphere.  then compare the distance from those 3 values to the center point, and if less than the radius, add them to a list of "is inside the sphere" coordinates.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer. I did the 3 nested for-loop one. Definitely helped! I think your answer is faster when the radius is large.

Comment: you're welcome.  ...you flagged it with numpy, so I gave you the numpy way (that I could think of).  but in this case, I think 3 nested loops would be faster and easier

Comment: if you try with a center `[-19, 110, 2129]` and a radius of `10` this doesnt work. Big values for center dont work here...